# card actions section always at the bottom of the card

Tags: html, css

What approach should i use in order to **have the actions section always at the bottom of the cards?**

Please see [CodePen](https://codepen.io/muscaiu/pen/eYWbKPO) for better understanding.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
    <div class="title">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia incidunt pariatur dicta deserunt neque vel magnam molestiae, animi optio ipsam alias accusamus quam excepturi ducimus suscipit sint amet, omnis mollitia.
    </div>
    <div class="middle">Middle Content</div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div>check availability</div>
        <button>Add to Wish</button>
        <button>Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="title">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia incidunt pariatur dicta deserunt
    </div>
            <div class="middle">Middle Content</div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div>check availability</div>
        <button>Add to Wish</button>
        <button>Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="title">Lorem ipsum, dolor s
    </div>
            <div class="middle">Middle Content</div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div>check availability</div>
        <button>Add to Wish</button>
        <button>Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
    display: flex;
 }
.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 20px;

.title{
    padding: 20px;
}
.middle{
    padding: 20px;
}
.actions{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `margin-top: auto`. That'll push the actions section down

```
.actions {
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I may have oversimplified the example lol! Thanks !

Comment: No, it was just the idea i needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having the container `div` having a position of `relative` and the item you wish to be at the bottom having an `absolute` position with the `bottom` set to `0px`

e.g.
In your CSS

```
...
.card {
    position: relative;
    ...
}
.actions {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px
    ...
}
```

You may still have to do some tweaking to your `.middle` class but this should hopefully give you a decent start